# undefined method `user_revisers_path' "NoMethodError in Revisers#new "

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I got this weird error I'm assuming this comes from the routes.rb part of my app.  Im trying to give the chance for a user to become a reviser when they enter a form. a user can only become a reviser once so its a `has_one reviser` on `user.rb` model Thanks!

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for :users ,
             :path => '' ,
             :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile' },
             :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks',
                              :registrations => 'registrations'
                             }

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do 
    resource :reviser
  end
```

**revisers_controller:**

```
class RevisersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reviser, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @reviser = current_user.reviser
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @reviser = current_user.build_reviser(params[:reviser])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @reviser = current_user.reviser.build(reviser_params)

    if @reviser.save
      redirect_to @reviser,notice: "saved...."
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    set_reviser
  end

  def update
    set_reviser

    if @reviser.update(reviser_params)
      redirect_to @reviser, notice: "updated.."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 
  def set_reviser
    @reviser = Reviser.find(params[:id])
  end

  def reviser_params
    params.require(:reviser).permit(:description, :average_start, :average_end, :max_pages, :price_per, :active)
  end
end
```

**new.html**

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @reviser] do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div.col-md-4 select">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>dsd</label>
        <%= f.input :description, label: false, class: 'controls',:input_html => { :id => 'description' } %>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Become Adviser", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Error log:**

```
Rendered revisers/_form.html.erb (14.7ms)
  Rendered revisers/new.html.erb within layouts/application (15.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_revisers_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faf35f0cc60>:0x007faf35ee7e60>):
     5:     <div class="panel-body">
     6:         <div class="container">
     7: 
     8:         <%= form_for [current_user, @reviser] do |f| %>
     9: 
    10:         <div class="row">
    11:             <div class="div.col-md-4 select">
  app/views/revisers/_form.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_revisers__form_html_erb___2471522092853631188_70195335070980'
  app/views/revisers/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_revisers_new_html_erb___1451348464463745171_70195280947160'
```

**Rake routes:**

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                        Controller#Action
                                 root GET      /                                                  pages#home
                     new_user_session GET      /login(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#new
                         user_session POST     /login(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#create
                 destroy_user_session DELETE   /logout(.:format)                                  devise/sessions#destroy
              user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /auth/:provider(.:format)                          omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
               user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /auth/:action/callback(.:format)                   omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
                        user_password POST     /password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#create
                    new_user_password GET      /password/new(.:format)                            devise/passwords#new
                   edit_user_password GET      /password/edit(.:format)                           devise/passwords#edit
                                      PATCH    /password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT      /password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#update
             cancel_user_registration GET      /cancel(.:format)                                  registrations#cancel
                    user_registration POST     /                                                  registrations#create
                new_user_registration GET      /sign_up(.:format)                                 registrations#new
               edit_user_registration GET      /profile(.:format)                                 registrations#edit
                                      PATCH    /                                                  registrations#update
                                      PUT      /                                                  registrations#update
                                      DELETE   /                                                  registrations#destroy
                    user_confirmation POST     /confirmation(.:format)                            devise/confirmations#create
                new_user_confirmation GET      /confirmation/new(.:format)                        devise/confirmations#new
                                      GET      /confirmation(.:format)                            devise/confirmations#show
                         user_reviser POST     /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#create
                     new_user_reviser GET      /users/:user_id/reviser/new(.:format)              revisers#new
                    edit_user_reviser GET      /users/:user_id/reviser/edit(.:format)             revisers#edit
                                      GET      /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#show
                                      PATCH    /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#update
                                      PUT      /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#update
                                      DELETE   /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#destroy
                                users GET      /users(.:format)                                   users#index
                                 user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                               users#show
                               photos GET      /photos(.:format)                                  photos#index
                                      POST     /photos(.:format)                                  photos#create
                            new_photo GET      /photos/new(.:format)                              photos#new
                           edit_photo GET      /photos/:id/edit(.:format)                         photos#edit
                                photo GET      /photos/:id(.:format)                              photos#show
                                      PATCH    /photos/:id(.:format)                              photos#update
                                      PUT      /photos/:id(.:format)                              photos#update
                                      DELETE   /photos/:id(.:format)                              photos#destroy
                                pages GET      /pages(.:format)                                   pages#index
                                      POST     /pages(.:format)                                   pages#create
                             new_page GET      /pages/new(.:format)                               pages#new
                            edit_page GET      /pages/:id/edit(.:format)                          pages#edit
                                 page GET      /pages/:id(.:format)                               pages#show
                                      PATCH    /pages/:id(.:format)                               pages#update
                                      PUT      /pages/:id(.:format)                               pages#update
                                      DELETE   /pages/:id(.:format)                               pages#destroy
autocomplete_user_country_suggestions GET      /suggestions/autocomplete_user_country(.:format)   suggestions#autocomplete_user_country
   autocomplete_user_city_suggestions GET      /suggestions/autocomplete_user_city(.:format)      suggestions#autocomplete_user_city
 autocomplete_user_school_suggestions GET      /suggestions/autocomplete_user_school(.:format)    suggestions#autocomplete_user_school
  autocomplete_user_major_suggestions GET      /suggestions/autocomplete_user_major(.:format)     suggestions#autocomplete_user_major
                          suggestions GET      /suggestions(.:format)                             suggestions#index
                                      POST     /suggestions(.:format)                             suggestions#create
                       new_suggestion GET      /suggestions/new(.:format)                         suggestions#new
                      edit_suggestion GET      /suggestions/:id/edit(.:format)                    suggestions#edit
                           suggestion GET      /suggestions/:id(.:format)                         suggestions#show
                                      PATCH    /suggestions/:id(.:format)                         suggestions#update
                                      PUT      /suggestions/:id(.:format)                         suggestions#update
                                      DELETE   /suggestions/:id(.:format)                         suggestions#destroy
                conversation_messages GET      /conversations/:conversation_id/messages(.:format) messages#index
                                      POST     /conversations/:conversation_id/messages(.:format) messages#create
                        conversations GET      /conversations(.:format)                           conversations#index
                                      POST     /conversations(.:format)                           conversations#create
                        post_comments GET      /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                 comments#index
                                      POST     /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                 comments#create
                     new_post_comment GET      /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)             comments#new
                    edit_post_comment GET      /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)        comments#edit
                         post_comment GET      /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)             comments#show
                                      PATCH    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)             comments#update
                                      PUT      /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)             comments#update
                                      DELETE   /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)             comments#destroy
                          post_places GET      /posts/:post_id/places(.:format)                   places#index
                                      POST     /posts/:post_id/places(.:format)                   places#create
                       new_post_place GET      /posts/:post_id/places/new(.:format)               places#new
                      edit_post_place GET      /posts/:post_id/places/:id/edit(.:format)          places#edit
                           post_place GET      /posts/:post_id/places/:id(.:format)               places#show
                                      PATCH    /posts/:post_id/places/:id(.:format)               places#update
                                      PUT      /posts/:post_id/places/:id(.:format)               places#update
                                      DELETE   /posts/:post_id/places/:id(.:format)               places#destroy
                                posts GET      /posts(.:format)                                   posts#index
                                      POST     /posts(.:format)                                   posts#create
                             new_post GET      /posts/new(.:format)                               posts#new
                            edit_post GET      /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                          posts#edit
                                 post GET      /posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#show
                                      PATCH    /posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#update
                                      PUT      /posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#update
                                      DELETE   /posts/:id(.:format)                               posts#destroy
```

Comment: Can you show the output of your `rake routes`?

Comment: haha the rake routes dont look so good when i post them. is there a better way or only show you the routes for revisers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a singular resource definition for your `:reviser` route. This makes sense for what you're trying to do, however the route generated by `form_for [current_user, @reviser]` will try to generate a route with both a `:user_id`, and an `:id` to identify your reviser.

So, the `:id` field isn't defined in your case since `resource :reviser` doesn't create an `:id`.

The solution is to explicitly set the url in your `form_for` to the route your want:

It should be something along the lines of:

```
form_for @reviser, url: edit_user_reviser_path(user_id: current_user.id)
```

The bigger issue with your code is that you're still directly referencing reviser by `id` in your controller. Under your current route settings, this will return an error on the `Reviser.find()` method. However, more importantly this presents a security concern since a malicious user could send an `id` param in the PATCH request to hijack and update a record that belongs to another user.

A simple solution  is to just reference the reviser object directly on current_user.

```
def set_reviser
  @reviser = current_user.reviser
end
```

Comment: o wow! thank you for the tip!! I wouldn't want any malicious users!!